# I am looking for authentication server for microservices, needs to have OpenID connect and LDAP support. UAA or Keycloak?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, keycloak, cloudfoundry-uaa

I am looking for a authentication server solution. It needs to have a SSO, OpenID Connect support and LDAP integration possibility.

Users will have 2 options to log in, either with their LDAP account or using external service which is based on OpenID connect protocol.

I have so far installed Keycloak, read all of the documents, integrated it with LDAP and made a small application to test it.

I have also worked through CloudFoundry UAA documents and tried to do some stuff using that solution.

Currently I am leaning towards using Keycloak but also UAA seems good. What else is out there which I could look into it before making a decision? It will be used in very large organisation.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Software recommendation related questions are usually out of scope in this site. We'll be happy to hear about your programming related issues!

Answer (score 0):

UAA is being used by numerous large organizations at scale by the likes of SAP (https://blogs.sap.com/2019/01/07/uaa-xsuaa-platform-uaa-cfuaa-what-is-it-all-about/), hundreds of Pivotal Cloud Foundry Customers Fortune 100/500 (https://docs.pivotal.io/p-identity/1-8/) and GE Predix as well.When scaled horizontally it has the ability to process tokens in the range of 1~2 million tokens per day. It is also kept up to date from a security/third-party CVEs stand point.
The primary use cases are as a Identity Proxy to be able to connect via LDAP/SAML/OIDC to enterprise identity providers. It is a certified OIDC identity provider as well.